# Did Hobab leave Moses in Numbers 10:29-31?

Tags: exodus, numbers, moses, niv

Numbers 10:29-31 NIV

29 Now Moses said to Hobab son of Reuel the Midianite, Moses’ father-in-law, “We are setting out for the place about which the Lord said, ‘I will give it to you.’ Come with us and we will treat you well, for the Lord has promised good things to Israel.”

30 He answered, ***“No, I will not go; I am going back to my own land and my own people***.”

31 But Moses said, “Please do not leave us. You know where we should camp in the wilderness, and you can be our eyes. 32 If you come with us, we will share with you whatever good things the Lord gives us.”

In the above text its not clear whether Hobab agreed to remain and guide Moses throughout their journeys or returned back to his native land

Did Hobab remain with Moses?

Answer (score 1):

Exodus 18:27

> Then Moses sent his father-in-law on his way, and Jethro returned to his own land.

Judges 1:16

> The descendants of Moses' father-in-law, the Kenite, went up from the City of Palms with the people of Judah to live among the inhabitants of the Desert of Judah in the Negev near Arad.

Moses' father-in-law went back to his own land. Yet, his descendants settled in Judah. Hobab was probably convinced by Moses to stay.